# The for loop not including the one part of the array that needs to be included

Tags: c++, arrays

This is my header file

```
#ifndef KINGDOM_H_
#define KINGDOM_H_

// TODO: sict namespace
using namespace std;
namespace sict {
    // TODO: define the structure Kingdom in the sict namespace
    class Kingdom {
    public:
        char m_name[32];
        int m_population;
    };

    // TODO: declare the function display(...),
    void display(const Kingdom&);
    void display(Kingdom pKingdom[], int kingdomNum);

    //         also in the sict namespace
}
#endif
```

and these two are my cpp files

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "Kingdom.h"
using namespace std;
// TODO: the sict namespace
namespace sict {


    // TODO:definition for display(...)
    void display(const Kingdom& pKingdom) {
        cout << pKingdom.m_name << ", population " << pKingdom.m_population << endl;

    }
    void display(Kingdom pKingdom[], int kingdomNum) {
        int total = 0;
        cout << "------------------------------" << endl;
        cout << "Kingdoms are" << endl;
        for (int i = 0; i < kingdomNum; i++) {
            cout << i + 1 << ". " << pKingdom[i].m_name << ", population" << pKingdom[i].m_population << endl;
            total += pKingdom[i].m_population;
        }
        cout << "------------------------------" << endl;
        cout << "Total population of SICT: " << total << endl;
        cout << "------------------------------" << endl;

    }


}




#include <iostream>
#include "Kingdom.h"

using namespace std;
using namespace sict;

void read(Kingdom&);

int main() {
    int count = 0; // the number of kingdoms in the array
    // TODO: declare the pKingdom pointer here (don't forget to initialize it)
    Kingdom* pKingdom = nullptr;


    cout << "==========\n"
        << "Input data\n"
        << "==========\n"
        << "Enter the number of Kingdoms: ";
    cin >> count;
    cin.ignore();

    if (count < 1) return 1;

    // TODO: allocate dynamic memory here for the pKingdom pointer
    pKingdom = new Kingdom[count];
    for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
        cout << "Kingdom #" << i + 1 << ": " << endl;
        // TODO: add code to accept user input for Kingdom i
        cout << "Enter the name of the Kingdom: ";
        cin >> pKingdom[i].m_name;
        cout << "Enter the number of people living in " << pKingdom[i].m_name << ": ";
        cin >> pKingdom[i].m_population;
    }
    cout << "==========" << endl << endl;

    // testing that "display(...)" works
    cout << "------------------------------" << endl
        << "The 1st kingdom entered is" << endl
        << "------------------------------" << endl;
    display(pKingdom[0]);
    cout << "------------------------------" << endl << endl;


    // add the new Kingdom
    cout << "==========\n"
        << "Input data\n"
        << "==========\n"
        << "Kingdom #" << count + 1 << ": " << endl;
    // TODO: accept input for the new element in the array
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        count = 1;
        cout << "Enter the name of the Kingdom: ";
        cin >> pKingdom[i].m_name;
        cout << "Enter the number of people living in " << pKingdom[i].m_name << ": ";
        cin >> pKingdom[i].m_population;

    }
    count++;
    cout << "==========\n" << endl;

    // testing that the overload of "display(...)" works
    display(pKingdom, count);
    cout << endl;

    // TODO: deallocate the dynamic memory here
    delete[] pKingdom;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

// read accepts data for a Kingdom from standard input
//
void read(Kingdom& kingdom) {
    cout << "Enter the name of the Kingdom: ";
    cin.get(kingdom.m_name, 32, '\n');
    cin.ignore(2000, '\n');
    cout << "Enter the number of people living in " << kingdom.m_name << ": ";
    cin >> kingdom.m_population;
    cin.ignore(2000, '\n');
}
```

and the output should ask the user for number of kingdoms and depending on the number of kingdoms,

it will ask the number of same two questions which are asking for the name of kingdom and number of people living in the kingdom repeatedly until the loop is finished.

Now once the console proceeds to Kingdom#3 and the user types everything, at the last procedure where it would state all the kingdoms's names and population that belong in SICT namespace,

but the code won't put the Kingdom #3's information and the total population would be calculated without Kingdom #3's information.

### So, it should look like this :

### Kingdoms of SICT

1. The_Vale, population 234567
2. The_Reach, population 567890

   ### 3. The_Riverlands, population 123456

### Total population of SICT: 925913

but it only prints

---

### Kingdoms of SICT

1. The_Vale, population 234567

   ### 2. The_Reach, population 567890

### Total population of SICT: 603,428

Can anyone tell me why and how to fix the problem?

Comment: Yeah, heard about tha approach as well, but II was assigned to use allocated array,

Comment: To  fix your problem: sign up for a better course.

Comment: When you add the other kingdom after the loop. You overwrite the first one because `i == 0`. Instead you should start that loop not at zero but at the number of kingdoms already entered. Of course vector would provide `push_back`. To debug issues like these you should become acquainted with a debugger. There is normally a learning curve associated with this and the interim solution until you grok debuggers is to just stick a load of `cout`'s in there.

Comment: Of course you'd need to make your allocation bigger to handle more kingdoms. Vector does that automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Your `display` function is fine, but your input is a mess...

You should be using a std::vector or list as other comments mentioned, but if you have to use a raw array, you need to remember where in the array you're changing data, and to allocate a new array and copy the data when you need it to be bigger.

If your second round of input is only supposed to read one element, it shouldn't be a loop.

You should also be using your `read` function instead of duplicating your input code, and likewise, you should be using your "Display(...)" function in your "display all" function instead of duplicating code.